# PHP image create from jpeg black output when using dynamic variable

Tags: php, jpeg

I'm trying to crop and resize images.

Working code:

```
$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$file = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'file', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$suffix = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'suffix', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

//Basic Setup
$jpeg_quality = 90;
$src = '../images/uploads/023328002_mv_zm_5562edfb32d19.jpg';
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);

//wide image output 
$path_wide = '../images/jewelry/wide/'.$id.$suffix.'.jpg';
$dst_wide = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );
imagecopyresampled($dst_wide,$img,0,0,$x,$y,$targ_w,$targ_h,$width,$height);
imagejpeg($dst_wide,$path_wide,$jpeg_quality);
```

Not working when change `$src` like this:

```
$src = '../images/uploads/'.$file;
```

The echo result for `$src` is:

```
$src = '../images/uploads/'.$file;
echo $src;
output:
../images/uploads/023328002_mv_zm_5562edfb32d19.jpg
```

The path is tested when using it in this:

```
<img src="../images/uploads/<?php echo $file; ?>" id="cropbox" alt=""/>
```

the image appeared with no problems

The path has no spaces or weird characters, and i tried `urlencode()` & `urldecode()` anyway..

Also tried converting to `(string)` with no luck..

Infact i have problems with all the 3  variables `$id`, `$file`, and `$suffix` which seems to have the right content when echo them, but still not working..

The image output is black square (but correct size) and with no name like `$id` and `$suffix` are empty:

```
$path_wide = '../images/jewelry/wide/'.$id.$suffix.'.jpg';
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Use double quotes for that string and see.

Comment: tried that, not working..

Answer (score 0):

I just found what is wrong with the code, the get variables wasn't available after the the submission of another post form in the page so i had to pass the values again in the post form..